# Stringbuilder for Constants

Tags: java

In application, we are using lot of SQL queries which we are assigning it in a String constants. So my question is by replacing String with StringBuilder ,whether it can improve the performance as we have to do lot of concatenations for large SQL queries. That is in the below two approaches, which is the best approach:

Approach 1:

```
String sql= "select * from table1" + " table2 where column = :1";
```

Approach 2:

```
StringBuilder sql =  new StringBuilder("select * from table1").
                              append( "table2 where column = :1" );
```

Can anyone suggest

Comment: The first approach is more efficient. The concatenation is performed at compile-time. Note that your second example is currently broken - it contains "table1table2" rather than "table1 table2".

Comment: No, replacing string concatenation by explicit use of `StringBuilder` will not at all improve performance and will only make your code more verbose.

Comment: No; this will make things slower. The compiler concatenates constants at compile time.

Comment: A `StringBuilder` can be mutated, so it’s not a constant at all.

Comment: Do you mean *String literals* or *String contstants*?

Comment: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 3):

Use string concatenation (with the `+` operator).

- If the expressions are compile-time constant expressions then they will be evaluated at compile time.
- If they are not; e.g.

  ```
   String sql = "select * from " + tableName() + " where column = :1";
  ```

  it is still better to let the compiler(s) optimize the concatenation, whether the expression is (runtime) constant or not.  They should turn the above into equivalent code using `StringBuilder`.

The only scenario where you should consider using `StringBuilder` explicitly is when you are doing things like this:

```
   String sql= "select * from table where ";
   for (String part: parts) {
      sql +=  part + " ";
   }
```

Current generation compilers cannot optimize the above.

Finally, do not use `StringBuilder` to *represent* constants.  They are mutable ... not constant.

---

<sup>Author note: the above examples are for illustration only.  Think SQL injection!  Use PreparedStatement.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, Just confirming my understanding is correct . Compiler will automatically convert the string concat operations using '+' into String Builder append. If so, it should work as same for  the third scenario also right. Just I need clarity for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use stringbuilder, you can of course to make anywhere- some *common utils class / DB utils* usually, method like following.

> but I dont think it will have better performance (or maybe yes, I guess it will dont be something extra improvement) for this case. From my point of view is looks *@Stephen C* example better

```
public static String composeSQLQuery(String columns,String tableName,String restrictions) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Select");
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(columns);
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append("from");
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(tableName);
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append("where");
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(restrictions);
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it's no need to use Stringbuilder, because from the jdk5, the compiler automatically convert concentration to stringbuilder.
For example:

```
    String a = "abc" + "def" + "xyz";
```

is equivalent with:

```
    Stringbuilder a = new Stringbuilder();
    a.append("abc");
    a.append("def");
    a.append("xyz");
```

But in case the concentration is in the loop, like:

```
    String a = "";
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        a += "str";
    }
```

Then, you should need to use Stringbuilder instead, because in this case, java cannot optimize the code and convert the concentration to Stringbuilder automatically.