# Using StringBuilder for constant strings in C#?

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

In my current project they put every SQL query in a "QueryList" Class, each of them is a different Get method.
What I don't understand is that they use StringBuilder in these methods to build a constant string, no manipulation or concatenation is used in them. When I questioned this, they said it was better then using concatenation.
To what I know, concatenation of string literals is solved by the compiler, right? Is there some optimization for this kind of StringBuilder code in the compiler too?

I saw this similar question in Java ([Stringbuilder for Constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827944/stringbuilder-for-constants)), should be the same for C# ?

```cs
public static class QueryList
{
    private static StringBuilder GetQuery
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

            query.Append(" INSERT INTO ");
            query.Append("  MyTable  ");
            query.Append("  (column1, column2)  ");
            query.Append(" VALUES ");
            query.Append("  (@val1 , @val2) ");

            return query;
        }
    }
}
```

and then in it's called as

```cs
string query = QueryList.GetQuery.ToString();
```

I made some counting and there's ~700 calls to these kind of methods, all followed by a ".ToString();"
I know that when making actual string concatenation it'll be better, but there's only 34 calls that need it.
There's something like 200 queries per seccond by the program.

Comment: don't do that. constants are done at compile time. this is needlessly creating a stringbuilder and doing work.

Comment: StringBuilder let you work with large and/or a lot of concatenation, to "solve" the immutability problem. Also if those are constants that's really uneccesry

Comment: if you are concating literal strings, c# will lower those into a single string.

Comment: I've already saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56970972/using-stringbuilder-for-constant-strings) today

Comment: And it's not like you'd have to use concatenation anyway. Just use a verbatim string if you need to maintain the line breaks / formatting...

Comment: I edited my answer to include a counterexample that shows why their supposed optimization is actually considerably less efficient than the alternatives - it's doing stuff at runtime that could easily be done at compile time. I show in my answer that, when you're concatenating string literals at compile time, any decent compiler will be smart enough to realize that it should do the concatenation at compile time rather than at runtime. In fact, using `StringBuilder` instead of string literals results in IL that's more than twice as long for my example.

Comment: @AleksAndreev Yes, it was also me, but using the wrong account. And I hadn't put code sample in that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no optimization here - using the StringBuilder is not only pointless, but actively harmful to the code's efficiency. The property in question will always return the following string:

```
INSERT INTO   MyTable    (column1, column2)   VALUES   (@val1 , @val2)
```

That being said, if you're concatenating multiple string literals, any modern C# compiler will realize that it should do that at compile time rather than runtime. By way of example, consider the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    string a = "a" + "b" + "c";
    string b = "def";

    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

Using LINQpad 5, this compiles to the following IL:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldstr       "abc"
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0007:  ldstr       "def"
IL_000C:  stloc.1     // b
IL_000D:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_000E:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0013:  nop         
IL_0014:  ldloc.1     // b
IL_0015:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_001A:  nop         
IL_001B:  ret
```

Note in particular that `"a" + "b" + "c"` and `"def"` both result in the exact same IL - in other words, the tool is smart enough to realize that `"a" + "b" + "c"` is exactly the same as `"abc"`.

Now, consider this code:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new StringBuilder();
    a.Append("a");
    a.Append("b");
    a.Append("c");
    string b = "def";

    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

This translates to the following IL:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      System.Text.StringBuilder..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0008:  ldstr       "a"
IL_000D:  callvirt    System.Text.StringBuilder.Append
IL_0012:  pop         
IL_0013:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0014:  ldstr       "b"
IL_0019:  callvirt    System.Text.StringBuilder.Append
IL_001E:  pop         
IL_001F:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0020:  ldstr       "c"
IL_0025:  callvirt    System.Text.StringBuilder.Append
IL_002A:  pop         
IL_002B:  ldstr       "def"
IL_0030:  stloc.1     // b
IL_0031:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0032:  callvirt    System.Object.ToString
IL_0037:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_003C:  nop         
IL_003D:  ldloc.1     // b
IL_003E:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0043:  nop         
IL_0044:  ret
```

This is 25 instructions instead of 12 - in other words, the supposedly "better" code actually results in more than twice as much IL and greater memory consumption.

That being said, just use a literal `const string` (as some of the other answers have already pointed out).

It's also very strange to return a StringBuilder here unless they intend to add more stuff to the string later. If they're not doing that, they should just return a string. Or, in this case, a string constant would be even better, as @David Browne indicated.

This point may be a little more controversial, but making this a property rather than a public constant is kind of pointless and just adds needless overhead. Properties are ultimately syntactic sugar for method calls, whereas `const string` allows the compiler to do a text substitution at compile time rather than having to do a runtime method call.

**TL;DR** Just using a `const string` is far more efficient because the code shown in your example forces your program to do stuff at runtime that could easily be done at compile time.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to return a *constant* `string`, just do it:

```
    // I've removed "Get" from the name
    private const string Query = 
      @"INSERT INTO MyTable (
          column1, 
          column2)
        VALUES (
          @val1, 
          @val2)";
```

there is no need in `StringBuilder`

Comment: I agree. The code in question should just use the `const` "directly" and not bother with the unnecessary property or `StringBuilder`, since they just add overhead with no benefit.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there some optimization for this kind of StringBuilder code in the compiler

No.  It will run every time.

There's no perfect way to embed multi-line string literals in C# (unfortunately).  Of the options, this is my favorite for SQL queries:

```
        private static string SomeQuery
        {
            get
            {
                var query = @"
INSERT INTO
MyTable (column1, column2)
values (@val1, @val2)
";
                return query;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I find it more visually pleasing to indent the lines of SQL to line up given that whitespace doesn't matter in SQL queries.

Comment: I added an example of the resulting IL in my answer. In my example, using `StringBuilder` instead of doing something like what you suggest results in *more than twice* as many lines of IL vs. just using string literals.